# angular material snackbar undefined after project build

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, snackbar

I have an issue with angular material snackbar. It works on localhost, but after build process I got an error:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'openSnackBar')
```

I call a commonservce that provides snackbar func, from other service file.

call:

```
private async handle() {
    this.commonService.openSnackBar('test snackbar');
...
```

commonService:

```
 public openSnackBar(message: string, icon?: string) {
    return this.zone.run(() => {
      // this.snackbar.open(message, 'x', config);
      this._snackBar.open(message, icon, { horizontalPosition: this.horizontalPosition, verticalPosition: this.verticalPosition, duration: 3000 });
    });
  }
```

ps zoge was added, but nothing changed. still works on localhost but not after build process.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue. Method call was executed from constructor. Solution was inject dependant service to calling method inside constructor as method `param` and remove "`this`" from call method body.

```
constructor(private commonService: CommonService) {
  setTimeout(async () => {
    await this.handle(commonService);
    ...
```

execute:

```
private async handle(commonService: CommonService) {
    commonService.openSnackBar('test snackbar');
...
```